# ruby on rails merit gem setting level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

Is there is a way to change the user level, something like

user.set_rank(:level => 4)  ?

I need to change the user levels but redifining rank rules and running what is suggested here [Can the merit gem recalculate reputation and re-evaluate badges and ranks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793547/can-the-merit-gem-recalculate-reputation-and-re-evaluate-badges-and-ranks) does not work.

¿any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. You can do `user.update_column :level, 4` and it does so.

Further discussion in https://github.com/tute/merit/issues/190.