# How to 'back calculate' Merit points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

I'm trying to add a reputation system into an existing app using [Merit](https://github.com/merit-gem/merit).

I want to back calculate points for all users based on their historical activity. Merit has quite a complicated internal structure with several tables, and I think I may be missing some important steps. Below is what I have so far, and I'm grateful for pointers from anyone more familiar with this gem.

To keep things simple, let's say I want to

```
score 2, to: :user, on: 'comments#create'
```

and that I have a Comment table full of records that look something like this

```
Comment id: 56, content: "My comment", user_id: 247, commentable_id: 2, commentable_type: 'Object', created_at: "2016-04-04 08:56:17", updated_at: "2016-04-04 17:03:55">
```

My current approach looks like this

```
Comment.all.each do |c|
  score_point = Merit::Score::Point.create( num_point: 2, log: nil, created_at: c.created_at)
  action = Merit::Action.create(user_id: c.user_id, action_method: 'create', action_value: nil, had_errors: false, target_model: c.class.name, target_id: c.id, processed: true, created_at: c.created_at)
  activity_log = Merit::ActivityLog.create( action_id: action.id, related_change_type: "Merit::Score::Point", related_change_id: score_point.id, description: "", created_at: c.created_at) 
end
```

There is also a `Merit::Score` and `Merit::Sash` table, but I'm not clear on what these do and whether these records also need to be created.

Is there anything else that I have overlooked?

As an aside, what is the purpose of `Merit::Action.action_value`, `Merit::ActivityLog.description` and `Merit::Score::Point.log`, or are these simply free text strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merit has the ability to recompute reputation for every user from it's `Merit::Action`. In [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793547/can-the-merit-gem-recalculate-reputation-and-re-evaluate-badges-and-ranks/15994487#15994487) you can see how an existing application using merit might:

1. Delete all the logs, badges and points granted related to a user
2. Mark all the actions as `processed: false`
3. Recompute the now-unprocessed rules

In your particular case, the only Merit model you'd want to create is `action`, and initializing it as `processed: false` instead of `true`. `Merit::Action.check_unprocessed` should then recreate the reputation you seek.

[This wiki article](https://github.com/merit-gem/merit/wiki/General-merit-workflow) that explains merit internals might help you understand the logic behind these steps.

---

`Merit::Action.action_value`, `Merit::ActivityLog.description`, and `Merit::Score::Point.log` have no meaningful behavior in merit, and you can use them if needed.

Comment: thanks @TuteC, I had seen that SO answer previously but had perhaps misunderstood the subsequent comments. Thanks for clarifying!!

Comment: hi @tuteC, what format should `Merit::Action.target_model` be? Is it a pluralized lowercased representation of the model (e.g. comments)? I am having trouble generating points with this method. Running `Merit::Action.check_unprocessed` is correctly assigning badges, and adding records to `Merit::Score`, but `Merit::Score::Point` remains empty. I assume this is not the correct outcome, but can't seem to figure out the cause.

Comment: never mind, I needed to clear previous point definitions from memory `Merit::AppPointRules = Merit::PointRules.new.defined_rules`. all is now working. thanks for a great gem!!